# Vue mustache syntax - is it possible to use variable as a key to object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mustache

I am a beginner in Vue. I need to create template as follows:

```
<h3>{{message[{{language}}]}}</h3>
```

or

```
<h3>{{message.{{language}}}}</h3>
```

where `message` is an object and `language` is a string variable containing selected language (e.g. "en").

Above mentioned code does not work (error compiling template). Is there any solution for this?

EDIT – Example:

Let us say we have the object: `message = {en: "Welcome"}` and the string variable `language = "en"`.

Then I want to print `<h3>Welcome</h3>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):</strike>

```
<h3>{{`message[{{language}}]`}}</h3>
```

The preceding example will print:

```
message[{{language}}]
```

And if the message is variable, use `${variable_name}`:

```
<h3>{{`${message}[{{language}}]`}}</h3>
```

Are you trying to use like?

```
<h3>{{message[language]}}</h3>
```

Comment: The last variant is my goal. Let us say we have the object:
`message = {en: "Welcome"}` and `language = "en"`.
I want to print `<h3>Welcome</h3>`

Comment: You are right. My thoughts were overcomplicated – I supposed I have to differentiate somehow between those two variables. Thanks!